# ScrollView fading edge with background image: Text Cut off

Tags: android, background-image, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` within `ScrollView` with a background image. The problem I face is that in the custom background image, the position of the fading edge is beyond the white border of the background image. It is not very nice. How can I make the fading edge appear before the white border?

http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/6775/fadingedge.png

XML

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="240dip"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"        
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try using android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp" for your scrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad the `android:paddingTop="10dip"` and `android:paddingBottom="10dip"` to the `ScrollView` item. In this way, element in this container (your table here) will have "outter (top/bottom) margin".

Comment: this does the trick nicely! I was playing around with margins.. forgot the existence of padding

Answer (score 2):

Is your background image a 9-patch? 9-patches can define padding with their content region. This can be used to pad in the area that actually scrolls which will alter the position of the fading edges. It's also a nicer approach than defining padding by hand since the padding is visually dependent on the background asset you're using. It leaves only one place to define these parameters.

Note that as of Android 4.0 we've started moving away from the use of fading edges and when you target API 14 or above they are disabled by default. Our UX team isn't fond of how they visually combine with other elements of the UI and they are prohibitively expensive to render in hardware accelerated mode on some common mobile GPU architectures.

Comment: mine is not a 9-patch. I guess using padding is the only way for now.

Comment: For a container like this it really should be a 9-patch unless you can always guarantee this box will be the same size on all devices. 9-patches allow these types of containers to resize easily and let Android's layout system adapt to different screen dimensions.